# Solve $\sinh z = z$

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I have an equation,

> $$\sinh z =z, \ z\in\mathbb{C}$$

How to solve it?

**My question**

It's trivial to see that the $z=0$ is a solution of the equation. But I want to know if there exists a non-zero solution.

The equation is from the answer of my another question.

Comment: It is the same as solving $e^z-e^{-z}=2z$  I don't think there is another solution other than $0$ but I am not sure

Comment: @Theo Bendit I was wrong, deleted my post. Thanks.